# Filter dropdown results in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, dropdown

I have a sheet where I want to have a dropdown for each row, where the dropdown items are populated from a range on another sheet, but limited to only the items that match the product name.

Here is an example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ikh5mSflbsxp_vnhHzXp2X9rmzDKmaX6GEeRZ6KsdZ8/edit?usp=sharing

So, in this example, the "Document" dropdown for "Widget 3000" should show options for

```
Sales Report 2019
Sales Report 2020
Warranty Info
Press Release
```

and so on for the other products. Right now, the data validation is just showing all the documents for all products.

It's *kinda* like a dependent dropdown, but not really... Not sure how to approach it, any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: see your sheet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this per row:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Documents!B:B, Documents!A:A=A2))
```

[image]

then set up data validation per each row:

[image]

and use this in C2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A&B2:B, 
 {Documents!A:A&Documents!B:B, Documents!C:C}, 2, 0)))
```

[image]

and then hide auxiliary columns:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Excellent, thank you! It's a shame the dropdown can't be filtered directly, but this is a perfect workaround.